# Algorithm of A^B(A power B) for Big numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, biginteger, exponentiation

Can you help me to find Algorithim of A^B(A power B) for big numbers( say up to 9*10^18) without using any libraries(Like java Math.Biginteger)? I know JAVA, so it would be great if the code written in java.

Comment: there you go:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good algorithm for exponentiation is the [square and multiply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

[image: formula]

Below I have included some pseudo code from the same wikipedia article.

```
1.  y := 1; i := l-1
2.  while i > -1 do
3.      if ni=0 then y:=y2' i:=i-1
4.      else
5.          s:=max{i-k+1,0}
6.          while ns=0 do s:=s+1 [2]
7.          for h:=1 to i-s+1 do y:=y2
8.          u:=(ni,ni-1,....,ns)2
9.          y:=y*xu
10.         i:=s-1
11. return y
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not say whether only the arguments are assumed to be up to 9*10<sup>18</sup> or also the result.  This is important because the maximum arguments in this range are guaranteed to overflow any amount of RAM that you may at your disposal, making your task plainly impossible regardless of the algorithm.

Your question does not say why you would use Java but not `BigInteger` which would otherwise be perfect for the task.  Not using `BigInteger` amounts to reimplementing parts of `BigInteger`.  Is this a homework?

Try to devise such an algorithm.  Once you know how to do it, you'll find that Java has all the operations that you need to implement it: bitwise operators, shifts and multiplication.

As the first step, consider the case where the exponent is a power of two.  Are you able to compute efficiently A<sup>2</sup>, then A<sup>4</sup>, then A<sup>8</sup>, then A<sup>16</sup>?  Call these "basic powers".

If yes: are you able to combine any other exponent from the basic powers?  (Hint: convert the exponent to binary.  For example, A<sup>20</sup> = A<sup>16+4</sup> = A<sup>16</sup> * A<sup>4</sup>).

Implement that and you have solved your task.

As a stretch goal if you found the above easy enough: if you implemented the above using an array that stores all the basic powers, you may now be able to optimize it away, slightly speeding up your algorithm.  You need to keep only one basic power at a time.  The trick is to extract individual bits from the exponent by testing it with `exponent & 1 != 0`, and to shift all its bits right (with `exponent >>= 1` or with `exponent /= 2`), so that the bit in question is always in the least significant position (making whatever remained of the exponent odd or even).  If you traverse the bits in the exponent in this way, you can traverse the corresponding exponents in the same loop, multiplying together those that apply.

If you made it till here, you now have a Java implementation of square and multiply.